# Returns no facebook page access_token in PHP SDK

Tags: facebook, access-token

Currently i am developing a new facebook app that allows users to post into their pages. Facebook team approved the manage_pages & publish_actions permissions. Now the problem is app doesn't get access_token for pages. When querying `/user-id/accounts` nothing returns.

Comment: Have you debugged the access token you are using?

Comment: same in debug tool too. If i selected "Get Access Token" works fine at the same time if i selected "Get App Token" page access_token is missing.

Comment: That was not my question. Have you debugged the access token?

Comment: are you asking about App Access Token or Something else? Also I debugged App Access Token

Comment: It doesn't make sense that "when querying /user-id/accounts nothing returns.". There must be at least some output or an error message.

Comment: @Tobi really its strange no exception returns. simply gets empty `Array()`

Comment: You should check the real http response body from the Graph API call, and not what you application does with it.

Comment: @Tobi how? but its very simple to get page "access_token" if facebook team approves the "manage_pages" permission

Comment: @Tobi temporarily i sorted this issue by storing never expire page "access_token" in db but it needs to be fixed.

Comment: You need to fix your application then. You don't even show some code, how should somebody be able to help you?`

Comment: why my question is down voted?

Answer (score 0):

**To obtain a page access token** you need to start by **obtaining a user access token** and **asking for the manage_pages permission**. Once you have the user access token you then get the page access token via the Graph API.

only after that you can query

```
GET /{user-id}/accounts
```

and you get result like this:

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "category": "Product/service",
      "name": "Sample Page",
      "access_token": "{access-token}",
      "id": "1234567890",
      "perms": [
        "ADMINISTER",
        "EDIT_PROFILE",
        "CREATE_CONTENT",
        "MODERATE_CONTENT",
        "CREATE_ADS",
        "BASIC_ADMIN"
      ]
    }, 
}
```

read more https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens#pagetokens

Answer (score 0):

I applied a fix for this issue.. I hope its correct way

`$session = new FacebookSession( 'user-token' );`

`$accessToken = $session -> getAccessToken( );`

`$longsession = $longLivedAccessToken = $accessToken -> extend( );`

`$session = new FacebookSession( $longsession );`

`$request = new FacebookRequest( $session, 'GET', '/me/accounts' );`

`$pageList = $request -> execute( ) -> getGraphObject( ) -> asArray( );`

then i stored permanent page "access_token" in database for offline use.